# ImportError: cannot import name 'GaussianProcess' from 'sklearn.gaussian_process'

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

I was trying to kaggle kernel of [Bayesian Hyperparam Optimization of RF](https://www.kaggle.com/mpearmain/bayesianoptimization-of-random-forest). And I couldn't import `sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess`. Please help this poor scikit-learn newbie.

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess as GP
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Develop/PycharmProjects/reinforcement recommandation system/BNP/bayesianoptimization-of-random-forest.py", line 24, in <module>
    from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess as GP
ImportError: cannot import name 'GaussianProcess' from 'sklearn.gaussian_process' (C:\Users\Develop\PycharmProjects\reinforcement recommandation system\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The code you link to is 4 years old, when probably the scikit-learn API was different in this case; see answer below

Comment: For those following the relatively old book (but still one of the best introductions on the topic imho)  *Python Data Science Handbook* and reaching this error, see [this code](https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/issues/165) for the current version of the module (using `GaussianProcessRegressor`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on whether you need the regressor or classifier:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor as GP

from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier as GP
```

Also, have a look at the different [modules](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.gaussian_process)

Comment: thanks, but.. I wanted to know how to use this like this: gp = GP(theta0=numpy.random.uniform(0.001, 0.05, self.dim), random_start=25).  GaussianProcessRegressor and GaussianProcessClassifier don't have argument like 'theta0' :(

Comment: 이희웅 I understand but please open another question or update your current one if your doubt is about how to use `GaussianProcessRegressor` or `GaussianProcessClassifier`. Regarding your comment, the functions can take the hyperparameter theta as parameter in _optimizer_. Have a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html  in the _optimizer_ paramter

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use the old `scikit-learn version 0.15-git`

The documentation for `sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess` is located here:
https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess.html

I just had the same problem, but I will move on to try to understand if `sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor` in the current version `scikit-learn 1.0.2` will work for my purposes.